# Как реализовать запоминание того что нпс мертвые?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я делаю rpg на unity. У меня вопрос. Как реализовать запоминание того что нпс мертвые? 
И как это потом запихнуть в сохранение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

присвой каждому NPC айдишник + заведи список мертвых NPC, который будешь сохранять в PlayerPrefs.

А потом убивай их после создания сцены :)

UPD: Или если ты создаешь их програмно -- не создавай, если они в списке мертвых.

Comment: Все же PlayerPrefs - не лучший способ хранить большие объемы информации. А так ответ хороший.

Comment: Ну, если NPC на уровне рельно большое количество и есть подключенная БД, то лучше в бд, да :)